# Getting segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

In my C code, I am getting a segmentation fault that I can't figure out. Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>   

#define MAX(x, y) (((x) > (y)) ? (x) : (y))
#define MIN(x, y) (((x) < (y)) ? (x) : (y))

int main() {    
    printf("a");
    time_t start_t, end_t;
    double diff_t;
    time(&start_t);

    int width = 440;
    int height = 280;
    int w = 25;
    int b = 15;
    int oo = 5;
    int pheight = 70;

    int m1, m2, m3, m4;
    double *points;
    printf("a");
    int data[2][width][height][width][height][height];
    printf("b");
    int side, ballx, bally, oballx, obally, py;

    for (side = 0; side < 2; side++) {
        for (ballx = w; ballx < width - w - b; ballx++) {
            for (bally = 0; bally < height - b; bally++) {
                if (side == 1) {
                    m1 = MAX(w, ballx - oo);
                    m2 = MIN(width - w - b, ballx);
                } else {
                    m1 = MAX(w, ballx);
                    m2 = MIN(width - w - b, ballx + oo);
                }
                for (oballx = m1; oballx < m2; oballx++) {
                    m3 = MAX(0, bally - oo);
                    m4 = MIN(height - b, bally + oo);
                    for (obally = m3; obally < m4; obally++) {
                        for (py = 0; py < height - pheight; py++) {
                            time(&end_t);
                            diff_t = difftime(end_t, start_t);
                            printf("side %d ballx %d bally %d oballx %d obally %d py %d time %f",
                                   side, ballx, bally, oballx, obally, py, diff_t);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What the * is this `int data[2][width][height][width][height][height];`?

Comment: That would be `8499814400000 * sizeof(int)`

Comment: thank you for a good laugh! made my day! +1

Comment: @omega: can you accept one of the answers?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that this is maybe not the cause of the problem but still worth to mention, that the `data` mega array is clearly too large for the stack size of your environment, thus your program is causing a *Stack Overflow*.

It uses 33999257600000 (*assuming `sizeof(int)` to be 4 which almost surely is the case*) bytes or 31664GB, that is a lot even to allocate on the heap,

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *example;
    example = malloc(33999257600000);
    if (example == NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "Impossible to allocate so much memory\n");
    free(example);
    return 0;
}
```

the code above will print `Impossible ...` on almost any nice machine with say 64GB of ram.

Comment: I put print statements as the first line but after running it, it didn't even print that?

Comment: @omega: it does not because you do not `fflush(stdout);` after `printf("a");`

Comment: @iharob: technically, the `data` array is not *used* in the function, so the compiler should not even bother allocating it from the stack... but it must be confused.

Comment: @omega: Excluding the occasional weird effects of compiler optimizations, _all_ stack space for all possible variables used in the function is reserved on entry to the function, it's not reserved piecemeal based on the line of declaration. It's much easier to reserve everything up front and return it all at once on return; it avoids conditional checks just to restore the stack pointer and avoids the need to back up the stack pointer in a base pointer register (freeing that register for general use). The actual stack reservation is happening _before_ the `printf`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: it may or may not be true in this particular case because `data` is technically a VLA whose size can be determined at compile time, but may be allocated dynamically at run time if the compiler does not optimize.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: as a matter of fact, what you describe is a possible implementation is the absence of VLA, but this behavior is not mandated by the C Standard and is usually impossible in presence of VLAs.

Answer (score 2):

It is uncertain why you define `data` this way:

```
int data[2][width][height][width][height][height];
```

But although `data` is not used in the `main` function, the compiler generates code to try and allocate it from automatic storage (aka *on the stack*).  This is way too large, so you invoke undefined behavior.

Your first and second `printf` do not make it to the console, most probably because you do not manually flush `stdout` before the crash.  Try `fflush(stdout);` after each debug `printf`.

Note that it is confusing to use variable names ending in `_t` such as `start_t`, `end_t` and `diff_t`.  This suffix is commonly reserved for types.

Also note for fun that making the screen larger may fix the problem:

```
int width = 8192;
int height = 4096;
```

will make `data` so large that its size will overflow 64 bits and boil down to `0` bytes.  The compiler may notice the overflow and complain or just generate code to allocate `0` bytes and run smoothly...  Both accepted instances of undefined behavior.